# Why can't they have the transporters alter appearance on away missions?

Tags: star-trek

I can't think of specific episodes off hand, but there were several episodes where crew members were surgically altered in order to appear as a different species if it is for espionage, etc.  While surgery in the future is much safer than today, and assuming the surgical reversal is easy and safe, if they are being transported anyway, why can't they have the transporters alter their appearance when they get reassembled?  I assume this would be the most ideal, no?

Comment: To my knowledge we have never seen the transporters intentionally used for biological alteration. What makes you believe this is even possible?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: the biofilters, and the ability to swap in different DNA sequences. For example, in the ST:TNG episode "Unnatural Selection", when the transporter was used to cure Dr Polaski of disease using her untainted DNA as a template. We're already at the dawn of DNA manipulation, whose to say in the 24th Century they havent a full understanding of what DNA strands do what and can't simply swap in modified DNA traits to alter appearance during transport, and then swap in the original DNA to filter out the alterations later.